# Can't install opencv-contrib-python

Tags: python, pip, opencv

I want to install opencv-contrib-python on my Raspberry pi4(Raspberry pi os)

When I execute this command:

`sudo pip3 install opencv-contrib-python`

I get the following error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting opencv-contrib-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/88/ed/87ee6dd3f3f578e1120ef38026b93aa4e78d30f0dc86f703b77bc971cd5c/opencv-contrib-python-4.5.3.56.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-n2u745p4 --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple --extra-index-url https://www.piwheels.org/simple -- setuptools wheel scikit-build cmake pip "numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='3.6' and platform_machine != 'aarch64' and platform_machine != 'arm64'" "numpy==1.19.3; python_version>='3.6' and sys_platform == 'linux' and platform_machine == 'aarch64'" "numpy==1.21.0; python_version>='3.6' and sys_platform == 'darwin' and platform_machine == 'arm64'" "numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='3.7' and platform_machine != 'aarch64' and platform_machine != 'arm64'" "numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='3.8' and platform_machine != 'aarch64' and platform_machine != 'arm64'" "numpy==1.19.3; python_version>='3.9' and platform_machine != 'aarch64' and platform_machine != 'arm64'":
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.6" and sys_platform == "linux" and platform_machine == "aarch64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.6" and sys_platform == "darwin" and platform_machine == "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.9" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bd/25/5bdf7f1adeebd4e3fa76b2e2f045ae53ee208e40a4231ad0f0c3007e4353/setuptools-57.4.0-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/63/39d04c74222770ed1589c0eaba06c05891801219272420b40311cd60c880/wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting scikit-build
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/78/c9/7c2c7397ea64e36ebb292446896edcdecbb8c1aa6b9a1a32f6f67984c3df/scikit_build-0.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting cmake
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/78/66d1a7c684cb3bdd2a037b4afc0becffd7b70587e8d2b15a38f1041d2e4c/cmake-3.21.0.tar.gz
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Collecting pip
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/ca/f0d790b6e18b3a6f3bd5e80c2ee4edbb5807286c21cdd0862ca933f751dd/pip-21.1.3-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting numpy==1.14.5
    Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/numpy/numpy-1.14.5-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
  Collecting distro (from scikit-build)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/b7/b3c4270a11414cb22c6352ebc7a83aaa3712043be29daa05018fd5a5c956/distro-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting packaging (from scikit-build)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/77/e2362b676dc5008d81be423070dd9577fa03be5da2ba1105811900fda546/packaging-21.0-py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting pyparsing>=2.0.2 (from packaging->scikit-build)
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/bb/488841f56197b13700afd5658fc279a2025a39e22449b7cf29864669b15d/pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Building wheels for collected packages: cmake
    Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cmake: started
    Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cmake: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-1h5tz_9d/cmake/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-tc247i0a --python-tag cp37:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-u3p5rnwd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 560, in setup
        cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-u3p5rnwd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 95, in __init__
        self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-u3p5rnwd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 82, in get_cmake_version
        "Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is %s" % cmake_executable)
  
    Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
  
    ----------------------------------------
    Failed building wheel for cmake
    Running setup.py clean for cmake
  Failed to build cmake
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, distro, pyparsing, packaging, scikit-build, cmake, pip, numpy
    Running setup.py install for cmake: started
      Running setup.py install for cmake: finished with status 'error'
      Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-1h5tz_9d/cmake/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-hscgf7fq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-n2u745p4 --compile:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-u3p5rnwd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 560, in setup
          cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-u3p5rnwd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 95, in __init__
          self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-u3p5rnwd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 82, in get_cmake_version
          "Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is %s" % cmake_executable)
  
      Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
  
      ----------------------------------------
  Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-1h5tz_9d/cmake/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-hscgf7fq/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-n2u745p4 --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-1h5tz_9d/cmake/
  
  ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-n2u745p4 --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple --extra-index-url https://www.piwheels.org/simple -- setuptools wheel scikit-build cmake pip "numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='3.6' and platform_machine != 'aarch64' and platform_machine != 'arm64'" "numpy==1.19.3; python_version>='3.6' and sys_platform == 'linux' and platform_machine == 'aarch64'" "numpy==1.21.0; python_version>='3.6' and sys_platform == 'darwin' and platform_machine == 'arm64'" "numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='3.7' and platform_machine != 'aarch64' and platform_machine != 'arm64'" "numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='3.8' and platform_machine != 'aarch64' and platform_machine != 'arm64'" "numpy==1.19.3; python_version>='3.9' and platform_machine != 'aarch64' and platform_machine != 'arm64'"" failed with error code 1 in None
```

My python version is:Python 3.7.3

pip version is:pip 21.1.3 from /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

Is the pip version inconsistency?

Comment: Are you familiar with virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, turns out you need to install OpenCV on RPi with `apt` and not `pip`. [This link](https://learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi/) helped me install OpenCV on RPi4. You need to manually install dependencies and then build the package from git. It's kind of a headache but did work.